# GraphQl: Cannot make a executable schema

Tags: typescript, graphql, backend

I am new to graphQL and only understand the basics of it. I am trying to create a mutation to register a user. I get an error when I try to use the makeExecutableSchema function from `graphql-tools`. This line in `index.ts` throws the error.

`schemas.push(makeExecutableSchema({ resolvers: resolver, typeDefs: typeDef }));`

This is the error.

`Error : "resolver" defined in resolver, but not in schema`

I am trying to loop through all the directories within the `modules` directory and make a executable schema from the resolver and schema files in each directory.

Here is my code.

index.ts

```
const folders = fs.readdirSync(join(__dirname, "./modules"));
  folders.forEach((folder) => {
    const resolver = require(`./modules/${folder}/resolvers`);
    const typeDef = loadSchemaSync(join(__dirname, `./modules/${folder}/schema.graphql`), { loaders: [new GraphQLFileLoader()] });

    schemas.push(makeExecutableSchema({ resolvers: resolver, typeDefs: typeDef }));
  });
```

./modules/register/resolver.ts

```
export const resolver: ResolverMap = {
  Mutation: {
    register: async (_: any, { email, password }: GQL.IRegisterOnMutationArguments) => {
      const hashedPw = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
      const user = User.create({ email, password: hashedPw });
      await user.save();
      return true;
    },
  },
};
```

./modules/register/schema.graphql

```
type Mutation {
  register(email: String!, password: String!): Boolean
}
```

I have inspected the typeDef variable in `index.ts` and it does include the `register` mutation.

Comment: The looping over folders adds some interesting complexity. If there is any mismatch at all between the resolvers and the typeDefs at any point you'll get the error. Try something simpler where you just define the executable schema from the typeDefs for `register` and the corresponding resolver. Also I'm not sure about an array of executable schemas, I haven't seen that pattern before. There's another way where you could combine all the resolvers and typedefs in the loop and then create a single executable schema post-loop.

Comment: I tried taking the typeDef and resolver out of the loop but it still gives me the same error. `const resolver = require("./modules/register/resolvers");`
  `const typeDef = loadSchemaSync(join(__dirname, "./modules/register/schema.graphql"), { loaders: [new GraphQLFileLoader()] });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found why it was giving the error. I removed the variable `resolver` in `resolvers.ts` and just did module.exports instead of creating a variable and exporting the variable.I guess the variable creates an extra layer around the mutation which the function cannot access.
We could also access it by doing resolver['resolver']